# Can WMI monitoring the event of formatting volume?

Tags: windows, powershell, format, wmi, volume

I want to implement a function is about `monitoring format volume`.

Is there any way to monitor the event of volume be formatted by using WMI or without using WMI?

I can use `Register-WmiEvent` to register a `Wmi Event monitor` to detect the plug/unplug of device (Below is sample code).

```
#Query for finding all device arrival events
$query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType=2"

#Register an event subscription
Register-WmiEvent -SourceIdentifier "Qsirch-Monitor-Volume-Add"  -Query $query -MessageData $yao -Action {
    $volumeName = (Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='$($Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.DriveName)'").VolumeName
  Write-Host "$($Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.DriveName) ($($volumeName)) was added"
} | Out-Null
```

When user create a new volume, this will print `D: (New Volume) was added`.

So can I use `Wmi Event` to achieve my goal?

Print `D: was formatting` when volume D was formatting.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `WHERE EventType=2` filter?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It doesn't work after removing WHERE filter. Maybe `Win32_VolumeChangeEvent` is not used to get the format event of volume, but I can't find any replacement to do it.